# Magento popup notification after submit newsletter

Tags: magento

Actually how to show magento success or error message notification after i submit the newsletter in lightbox ?

```
<block type="core/messages" name="global_messages" as="global_messages"/>

<div id="messages_product_view"><?php echo $this->getMessagesBlock()->getGroupedHtml() ?></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to give proper css to show messages in popup to the below classes.

```
  <ul class="messages">
        <li class="success-msg">
            <ul><li><span>Thank you for your subscription.</span></li></ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
```

same way you can give css for error and alert messages.

Hope this will work !!!